# jquery nthchild only works without 'child'

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

More out of curiosity than actual need of a solution. I have a script in which I am calling an nth-child, by accident I left off the child part and it worked. However, i caught the mistake and fixed it, but the script stopped working, so i took out 'child' again and the script worked again. It's in jquery btw. Anybody have a clue how this could be happening?

```
if($('#user1').children().children('tr:nth-child('+y+')').children('.user2:nth('+x+')').children().hasClass('leftborder')){
```

works

```
if($('#user1').children().children('tr:nth-child('+y+')').children('.user2:nth-child('+x+')').children().hasClass('leftborder')){
```

doesn't work

```
<table id="user1">
    <tr><!--row 1-->
        <td class="user1">
            <div class="up arrow"><div  class="upbutton button"></div></div>
            <div class="down arrow"><div class="downbutton button"></div></div>
            <div class="left arrow"><div class="leftbutton button"></div></div>
            <div class="right arrow"><div class="rightbutton button"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="user2">
            <div class="up arrow"><div  class="upbutton button"></div></div>
            <div class="down arrow"><div class="downbutton button"></div></div>
            <div class="left arrow"><div class="leftbutton button"></div></div>
            <div class="right arrow"><div class="rightbutton button"></div></div>
        </td>
```

is the general idea

and to clarify, the table is closed in my actual document and the if statement is finished as well, just not really relevant to this problem as far as I can tell.

it was pointed out nothing has class leftborder, this is added in earlier lines

```
$('.leftbutton').click(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().children('.left').toggleClass('leftborder');
```

and the values of x and y were requested

```
var rows=$('#user1').children().children().size();
    for(y=1;y<=rows;y++){
        var cols=$('#user1').children().children('tr:nth-        child('+y+')').children('.user1').size();
        for(x=1;x<=cols;x++){
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please click "edit" and add the relevant code to your question, both the working version and the non-working version.

Comment: sorry bout that, it has been done.

Comment: Depends largely on your DOM. Can you also include related DOM snippet?

Comment: What are the values of `x` and `y`? None of your elements have class `leftborder`, so both expressions should be `false`.

Comment: oh, that part is relevant, elsewhere in the jquery the class leftborder is assigned, I know that part is working. x and y are dependent on the size of the table, but they are the indexes of for loops that I know are going through the entire size of the table.